# Accelerometer tilt error  correction 

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

I am using arduino and accelerometer MMA7341 to measure the acceleration in x direction of an oscillating metal table. But the mounting of the accelerometer is tilted    by a small angle (say Q) . Is it affect the acceleration?. If it is affect the acceleration in x direction , how can correct it without changing the tilt of the acceleration  sensor.

Answer (score 1):

"Tilt" and "acceleration" are both the same, from the perspective of most sensors, since both measure a force, rather than an actual angle (tilt) or change in velocity (acceleration).

What you should do is make sure the object on which the sensor is mounted is "level", within the best of your ability to determine such a thing, and use the values from analogRead() or whatever else your device provides, as the "0" values.

For the MMA7341 you'll also need to calibrate your analog signals, or else use a high precision reference as input to the Aref pin, assuming you're Arduino exposes that pin.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what you are measuring. THe MMA7341 looks to be able to be used for acceleration as well as tilt. If you are measuring acceleration then the mounting position doesn't matter since acceleration is a change of velocity and the velocity delta will be constant regardless of orientation.

If you are measuring tilt then thats obviously different. You could theoretically measure the initial tilt and then compensate for that in your code if you wanted to of course.

Comment: Draw the force vectors for "acceleration" and "tilt".  That'll answer your "I think this depends" comment.